# If $A^2=\mathbb{I} (2\times 2$ identity) then $\mathbb{I} + A$ is invertible only if $A=\mathbb{I}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I want to show that if $A^2=\mathbb{I}$ ($2\times2$ identity) then $\mathbb{I} + A$ is invertible only if $A=\mathbb{I}$.

I know that $A^2=\mathbb{I}$ means that $A=A^{-1}$

I've started by letting $A=\begin{bmatrix} a&b\\c&d \end{bmatrix}$ and then $A+1=\begin{bmatrix} a+1&b\\c&d+1 \end{bmatrix}$ so it's invertible only when $(a+1)(d+1)-bc\neq 0$ and then I was going to see when this would be the case based on what we know about $A$ but this seems over complicated and I feel like there's a better way that I'm missing.

Comment: Just a note: Now that you're working with matrices, you should be careful to stop saying things like "$A^2 = I$ means that $A = A^{-1}$". It's something we're all used to from working with real numbers, but it's not necessarily true and it's a bad habit we all need to learn to break at some time.

Comment: When is it not true? $A^2=I\Rightarrow A^{-1}A^2=A^{-1}I \Rightarrow A=A^{-1}$

Comment: D'oh! You are right that it's true, but your proof of it assumes that $A$ is invertible, which is something you can't assume and need to establish. Apologies as my comment was wrong and misleading -- it's the habit of writing $A^{-1}$ without any justification that we need to break.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:** $$A(I+A)=I+A\,\,\,\,\,\,$$

Comment: I actually just got this at the exact same time :) 

So I have $A(A+I)=A+I \Rightarrow A=(A+I)(A+I)^{-1} = I$ but is this sufficient to show that $A+1$ is not invertible otherwise

Comment: @EveBellaqua In your question, you assume $I+A$ invertible. That is not something you want to show. Then converse of your statement is trivially true because if $A=I,$ then $I+A=2I$ is invertible.

Answer (score 1):

$(A + \mathbb I)(A - \mathbb I) = A^2 - \mathbb I = \mathbb I - \mathbb I = O.$ Because we know that $A^2 = \mathbb I$. As Sahiba Arora commented, $A + I$ is invertible, so $A - I = O$ and $A = \mathbb I$.

Comment: Note that in general if product of two matrices is $0,$ then both matrices may be non-zero. However, if $AB=0$ and $A$ is invertible, then $B=0.$ Therefore since $(A+I)(A-I)=0$ and $A+I$ is invertible, so $A-I=0.$

Comment: @SahibaArora thanks, I'll edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

First, $(I+A)^2=2(A+I)$, thus the eigenvalues of $I+A$ are among the roots of $X^2-2X$, that is to say $0$ and $2$. If $I+A$ is invertible then $0$ can’t be an eigenvalue of $I+A$, thus $I+A=2I$ and $A=I$ because for all invertible matrix $P$, we have $P(2I)P^{-1}=2I$.